# JavaScript Navigation Button Code Issue

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make this button work so it does not just "instantly" display the menu. When I added the .style.WebkitTransition content to my code, it broke the functionality. The button works without it, but it displays the content instantly. I want it to transition smoothly like it does on nice websites. I don't need a demonstration demo or anything, I just need a JavaScript guru to tell me how to go about achieving my desired results from this code. Thank you!

JavaScript

```
function mobileFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("JavaMenu").style.WebkitTransition = "ease 1s";
    if (x.className === "navbar") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "navbar";
    }
}
```

Comment: What you wanted was to wait for the element to finish animating before proceeding?

Comment: @masterpreenz I want the menu to display smoothly, right now it appears instantly when the mobile button is pressed. I was trying to use the ease transition with a 1 second duration here.

Comment: What makes it display? `display: block?` from `display: none;`? or `visibility`?

Comment: Where is your css for the transition?

Comment: BTW, you can toggle the `responsive` class with `x.classList.toggle('responsive')`.

Comment: @masterpreenz block is how it displays

Answer (score 0):

Use **max-height** instead of **height** in css

```js
function mobileFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("JavaMenu");
    x.style.transition = "ease 1s";
    document.getElementById('JavaMenu').classList.toggle('responsive');
}
```

```css
.navbar{ max-height:0; overflow:hidden; transition: ease 1s}
.navbar.responsive{ max-height: 200px;}
```

```html
<span onclick="mobileFunction()">Toggle Menu</span>
<ul id="JavaMenu" class="navbar">
<li>Menu 1</li>
<li>Menu 2</li>
<li>Menu 3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't possibly animate `display` property.

Use should add `top, left | margins | transform | opacity` to achieve effective animation effect, `display: block` only shows the element. The most effective way of animating a menu is to hide it by `display: none` and throw it away from your view `X = -MENU_WIDTH` **LEFT** or `X = SCREEN_WIDTH + MENU_WIDTH` **RIGHT** then do a sliding effect

```
// CSS
#JavaMenu {
   // hide it by default
   display: none;
   // width: 320px;
   // throw it off screen, give it -width or more than -width to effectively hide it
   transform: translateX(-320px);
   // you can just simply put the transition here:
   // transition: 1s ease;
}

// the show
#JavaMenu.responsive {
    // show it
    display: block;
    // move it on screen;
    transform: translateX(0);
}

// JS
// then toggle the classes as you did in your JS
// this will give it animation effect
```

Also instead of using `.className()` you can actually use `.classList.contains('navbar')` to check if `navbar` class exists, `classList.add(class)` to add and `classList.remove(class)` to remove.

hope that helps.